# Go back to Global Screen without exiting app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am a newbie at Blackberry development. I am making an app which I have set as System Module so that it will Run at startUp. This app has a listener which captures the event of an outgoing call and then asks the user for a confirmation. My problem is, I want to go back to the Calls List Screen (Global Screen) if the user selects NO. But, if I use System.exit(0), the listener stops, which is not desired. What I need to do is again send the App to background. Can someone help???

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vivart. That did work. But problem is that it brings me to phone's home screen and I want to go back to Calls List Screen.

I found an alternate solution -

Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, new PhoneArguments());

This line brings the Calls List Screen to foreground.

Thanks again for the quick response :)

Comment: You should put this as a comment to Vivart's question, not as a new answer

Comment: In my question I have stated that I want to go back to the Calls List Screen, not the Mobile Home Page. Vivart's answer partially solves my problem. Since I later found exactly what I needed, I thought I should post the solution for others' sake.

Answer (score 2):

you just want to send your application to background.

```
getApplication().requestBackground();
```

Comment: Thats a very useful piece! Will find it useful in future Blackberry App development work. Thanks a ton!